# Firefox addon popup JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, add-on

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css">
    <title>Youpotify</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="download">
        <div class="video">
            <button id="video">Download this video</button>
        </div>
        <div class="playlist">
            <button id="playlist">Download this playlist</button>
        </div>
        <div class="channel">
            <button id="channel">Download this channel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", () => {
            document.getElementById("video").style.backgroundcolor = "red";
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I loaded this addon on Temporary Extension and I click the button but the background color did not change.

I wanted to run my JavaScript file in firefox addon popup HTML file, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of potential issues here:

First, inline Javascript (inside `<script></script>` tags) is [not permitted by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy#inline_javascript).

To include Javascript to your popup, you need to put it into a separate Javascript file and reference is with:

```
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

where your `index.js` is in the same folder and has your code:

```js
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("video").style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Second,

```js
document.getElementById("video").style.backgroundcolor = "red";
```

has incorrect attribute, it should be `style.backgroundColor` with a capital C.

Comment: Then, How can I run my JavaScript code?

Comment: You can add it as a separate script. I'll edit in an example.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the accepted answer, you might also need to add the following to your manifest.json file:

Manifest v2:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
```

Manifest v3:

```
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"
  },
```